# Unicode symbols not displaying correctly in mobile devices

Tags: android, iphone, mobile, unicode, character

While I'm developing responsive website I have used this uni-code ( » ) to the read more links. It is displaying correctly in desktop browser but it is not displaying correctly in mobile devices like android or iPhone. Is it possible to display the same as in desktop..? What's the problem..? Whether the mobile device doesn't support uni-code..?

Comment: You need to provide a code sample showing how you load the URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in the embedded font you use, via `@font face`. The version used by Android is apparently broken. It does not display “»”, and it has problems with many other Latin 1 Supplement characters too, see my [test page](http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/test/droid.html). Something may have gone wrong when you set up the font files on your server.

The problem does not appear if you remove the `font-family` setting, letting each browser use its default font, or if you use Droid Sans as hosted by Google, using `<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Droid+Sans' rel='stylesheet'>` and `font-family: "Droid Sans", sans-serif`.

Comment: Hey thanks man...you are correct. The problem is from font face. It displays correctly when using from Google. Thanks a lot..!!!

Comment: indeed. in my case googleapis font was causing the problem and I couldn't see some characters in some android devices. I changed it to another google font supporting my language and it got fixed. Thanks Korpela

Answer (score 0):

The problem is most probably not in the display of a character (“»”, U+00BB RIGHT-POINTING DOUBLE ANGLE QUOTATION MARK, is very widely supported in fonts) but in the character encoding. If the encoding is not properly declared, different browsers may make different guesses.

Check out the W3C page [Character encodings](http://www.w3.org/International/O-charset.en.php), and make sure that the declared encoding matches the actual one.

If problems remain, please post a URL and explain what “is not displaying correctly” means (not displaying at all? space shown? some wrong characters shown? which?).

Comment: Actually I have used the HTML code (&#187;) in website to display the arrow. [check this website link](http://aparajayah.com/demo/aparajayah/16-08/) in mobile browser (preferably android browser). What I mean about displaying is it shows square brackets instead of arrows. But it displays correctly in opera mini browser in mobile.

Comment: In meanwhile while googled I have came across the [link](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/bb/index.htm). In that they shown some encoding value for this character like (11000010:10111011). Whether we have to use this code to display across all browsers and devices.

Comment: I see, I was wrong: it *is* a font problem after all. I’ll send another answer about that. By the way, what is displayed is a small rectangle, commonly used to denote missing glyph.

Answer (score -1):

android does not support special characters, in android we need to write  `&gt;` to show ">" character. why don't you use image instead of characters.

Comment: &gt; is html escaped > The problem is nothing to do with escaping.